# OracleSQL - Actualizar campos de una fila luego de unos minutos

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Estoy creando una tabla llamada **ORDENES** en oracle:

| hora | estado |
| --- | --- |
| 10:30 | En proceso |

Quiero que luego de 2 minutos la tabla se actualice y se vea de esta manera:

| hora | estado |
| --- | --- |
| 10:32 | Entregado |

¿Tal vez se tenga que crear la tabla de una manera diferente o hacer las inserciones de una manera diferente, o con procedures?

```
CREATE TABLE actualizaciones (
    hora TIMESTAMP,
    estado VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la garantía que la orden a los 2 minutos si fue puede pasar al estado "Entregado"?

Answer (score 3):

Tablas no cambian sus datos por su misma volontaridad.

Si quieres cambiar el estado en tu tabla despues de dos minutos hay dos possibilidades:

1. Escribes un proceso que recorre todos los registros cada minuto y cambia el estado 'En proceso' a 'Entregado' si han pasado dos minutos.
2. Escribes un trigger que invoca una función autonoma (`AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`) que espera dos minutos (`DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP`) y entonces hace el update.

El problema: Es normal en una base de datos que pueden pasar retardos, y por eso una consulta podría recibir estados desfasados.

Por eso pienso que sería mejor no cambiar el estado. Puedes insertar un estado NULL, y solamente cambias el estado si hay una situación que lo demanda. Entonces si encontramos un registro con el estado NULL miramos su timestamp y sabemos que el estado es 'En proceso' en los primeros dos minutos y 'Entregado' después.

Podemos escribir un VIEW para ver el estado real. Este es garantizado de darte los estados actuales, porque no haya ningun proceso que tenga que cambiar algo, solo vemos a los campos de la tabla y los interpretamos.

```
CREATE VIEW ordenes_actuales AS
  SELECT
    hora,
    CASE WHEN estado IS NOT NULL
         THEN estado
         ELSE CASE WHEN hora < SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2' MINUTE
                   THEN 'En proceso'
                   ELSE 'Entregado'
              END
    END AS estado_actual
  FROM ordenes;
```

Más corto:

```
CREATE VIEW ordenes_actuales AS
  SELECT
    hora,
    CASE WHEN estado IS NOT NULL                         THEN estado
         WHEN hora < SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2' MINUTE  THEN 'En proceso'
                                                         ELSE 'Entregado'
    END AS estado_actual
  FROM ordenes;
```

Comment: La opción 2 no es muy recomendable, ya que bloquearía la tabla o el registro para otra acciones; tal vez mas bien crear un job o un scheduler job que realice el update a los 2 minutos

Comment: @alvalongo: Parece que no has leído mi respuesta. Es verdad, la opción #2 no es recomendable, pero la opción #1 tampoco. Por eso estoy sugeriendo una tercera opción en mi respuesta.